# Couchbase view on multiple columns with WHERE and ORDER BY clause as in SQL

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view, spring-data-couchbase

I am new to Couchbase noSql database.

I am trying to create a view, i want this view should give result as below SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM Employee e WHERE e.name = "DESM%" AND e.salary < 1000 ORDER BY e.id desc
```

Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Comment: `ORDER BY` in a view is either a non-standard language feature or an error. If you want to replicate some non-standard behaviour, you'll have to be more specific than "SQL" - what SQL database *product* are you trying to replicate the behaviour of? (In standard SQL, tables and views are *unordered* bags of rows - so an `ORDER BY` within a view doesn't make sense)

Comment: I got your point. My intention is to query Couchbase as above mentioned sql query. In which way i can achieve it. Any suggestion for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at existing beer samples in Couchbase (it comes with it), you will find views defined there. In admin console you can run a view. Notice when you run a view you can provide filtering criteria and sort order for the result...that might be an equivalent for your SQL like functionality. Read more on [Views and Indexes](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-intro.html)

yet another option is to use Couchbase v3 that comes with its own [N1QL query language](http://docs.couchbase.com/prebuilt/n1ql/n1ql-dp3/) that can serve as another alternative. You can try it out online [here](http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial).