# querying couchbase with spring-data-couchbase, using multiple columns

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-view, spring-data-couchbase

I am using couchbase3 with **spring-data-couchbase**, and want to query data using spring data repository with multiple columns.

```
public interface UserAccountRepository extends CrudRepository<UserAccount, Long> {
public UserAccount findByEmail(Query eMail);
public UserAccount findByEmailAndStatus(Query query); // fn with multiple column, but not getting the result
}
```

How should I write Map function and Reduce function for the same?

For the function **findByEmail(Query eMail);** to work, I have added the view with Map fn()

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit(doc.email,doc);
}
```

This view have email as key, and value is the document.
But if i need to query using email and status? How should the view look like ?

I have seen this link, but not very clear.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938755](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938755/couchbase-view-on-multiple-columns-with-where-and-order-by-clause-as-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able make springdata function to invoke a compound Key view.
My Document name is : Data
**Compound Key View**

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc && doc._class == "com.couchbase.entity.Data"){
    emit([doc.key1, doc.key2], doc);
  }
}
```

**SpringData Repository Inferface shown below :**

```
package com.couchbase.repository;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.view.View;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.Query;
import com.couchbase.entity.Data;

public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<Data, String> {

    @View(designDocument="Data",viewName="findByKey1AndKey2")
    public List<Data> findByKey1AndKey2(Query query);
}
```

**Test Class shown below :**

```
import com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.ComplexKey;
import com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.Query;

public class DataTest extends WebAppConfigurationAware{

    @Autowired
    private DataRepository dataRepository;

    @Test
    public void testStringDataCompoundQuery(){
        Object[] objArr = new Object[2];
        objArr[0] = "aaa";
        objArr[1] = 1;

        Query query = new Query();
        query.setKey(ComplexKey.of(objArr));

        System.out.println(dataRepository.findByKey1AndKey2(query));

    }
}
```

If this was useful for you, please up vote

Answer (score 0):

You could use compound key like describe in the documentation here: http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/compound-keys.html

Comment: is it possible to query view's with compound keys using 'spring data' ?

Comment: Yes, you have a direct access to the Couchbase Java SDK if you use Spring Data. You can inject the CouchbaseClient Bean.